# Is there any octave code for defining the variables?

Tags: octave

How can I define these variables in Octave code? All-items HICP (CP00), Energy (NRG) and Overall index excluding energy (TOT X NRG)

```
month_on_month_hicp = diff(hicp) ./ hicp(1:end-1);

month_on_month_energy = diff(energy) ./ energy(1:end-1);

month_on_month_non_energy = diff(non_energy) ./ non_energy(1:end-1);
```

> error: 'hicp' undefined.

I get this error for not defining the variables. Please help me with this.

I need octave code to define these 3 variables.

Comment: How can you expect a pertinent answer to this question? This is your code, and for us it's impossible to have the slightest idea why `hicp` is not defined and how it should be defined.

Answer (score -1):

variables could be defined by two ways:

1)directly in te code, separatign elements of a line by space or coma, and elements of different lines by semi colon.

example: x=[12,42,13;15,17,22];

this will produce a 2 by 3 matrix "x".

2)reading variables from a text or a binary file.

Comment: Not only there are other ways to "define" a variable in Octave, but how does it help if you don't know what for instance `hicp` is supposed to contain in the piece of code shown by the OP?